Drawing arcs in PyLaTeX
I want to draw 2 arcs connected in the middle with pylatex but I have no clue how to go about it.
The latex code is as below.
    \draw[thick,red] ([shift=(38.9:2cm)]-1.75,0) arc (38.9:321:2cm);
    \draw[thick,red] ([shift=(210.9:2.5cm)]2,0) arc (210.9:510.1:2.5cm);

But when I tried to do it in PyLaTeX, the code below returned an error.
tikz.append(TikZDraw(
            path=[
                TikZCoordinate(0, 0),  # Starting point
                NoEscape("arc")  # Arc definition
            ],
            options="thick, blue"  # Line style
        ))

with error
File "/home/path/generate_latex.py", line 125, in generate_latex_with_pylatex
    tikz.append(TikZDraw(
                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/path/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pylatex/tikz.py", line 492, in __init__
    self.options.append_positional("draw")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append_positional'

I did a few attempts at this as shown below with the error attached. I also found out that with TikZDraw it does not create a \draw command but rather a \path command which confused me a little as i have no clue how to create an arc with \path. If there is an alternative method to create a peanut shape as shown in the image that will be kindly appreciated too. 
Here is the other attempt.
arc_path = TikZPathList([TikZCoordinate(0, 0),"arc"])  # Arc definition
        
        tikz.append(TikZDraw(path=arc_path, options="thick, blue"))

with error
File "/home/path/generate_latex.py", line 114, in generate_latex_with_pylatex
    arc_path = TikZPathList([TikZCoordinate(0, 0),"arc"])  # Arc definition
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/path/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pylatex/tikz.py", line 320, in __init__
    self._parse_arg_list(args)
  File "/home/path/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pylatex/tikz.py", line 376, in _parse_arg_list
    self._parse_next_item(item)
  File "/home/path/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pylatex/tikz.py", line 333, in _parse_next_item
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: First element of path list must be a node identifier or coordinate

when i checked TikZPathList, it is shown that _legal_path_types = ["--", "-|", "|-", "to", "rectangle", "circle", "arc", "edge"], which makes me believe that arc is doable too but i have no clue what the format of the code should be like.

welcome! if nobody answers this, I suggest asking on a site about python as I'm not sure how many people use pylatex and those look like python errors rather than anything on the tex side. for this site, you should please post a minimal (non-)working example i.e. something we can compile to reproduce the error you want help with. (presumably that would be a python script of some kind.) \draw is just \path [draw] so there is no need for it to accept a separate thing, provided the one for path can accept the draw option. refer to the pgf/tikz manual for syntax of e.g. arc.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you @cfr! will do so next time!

You can use the syntax TikZDraw([TikZCoordinate(x, y), "arc"]) and specify the options of the arc using the full option names start angle, end angle, radius instead of the shorthand (start:end:radius).
I'm not sure if PyLaTeX supports shift for coordinates, but if you want to use the TikZCoordinate class then you can to apply the shift manually (i.e., adjusting the coordinate numbers instead of adding shift).
Python code:
from pylatex import (
    Document,
    TikZ,
    TikZCoordinate,
    TikZDraw,
    TikZOptions,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create document
    doc = Document()

    # add our sample drawings
    with doc.create(TikZ()) as pic:
        pic.append(
            TikZDraw(
                [TikZCoordinate(2, 2.5), "arc"],
                options=TikZOptions("red", "start angle=38.9", "end angle=321", "radius=2cm")
            )
        )
        pic.append(
            TikZDraw(
                [TikZCoordinate(2, 0), "arc"],
                options=TikZOptions("red", "start angle=210.9", "end angle=510.1", "radius=2.5cm")
            )
        )

    doc.generate_pdf("tikzdraw", clean_tex=False)

Generated LaTeX:
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
%
%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\path[red,start angle=38.9,end angle=321,radius=2cm,draw] (2.0,2.5) arc;%
\path[red,start angle=210.9,end angle=510.1,radius=2.5cm,draw] (2.0,0.0) arc;%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}

Note that this is different from normal TikZ syntax for arcs, which would be:
\draw (2.0,2.5) arc [start angle=38.9, end angle=321, radius=2cm];

The difference of \path[draw] vs. \draw is not important, however the PyLaTeX output puts the arc options in the path instead of after the arc specifier. TikZ does not seem to care though, the compilation runs without errors or warnings and produces the following figure:


amazing! Thank you very much! exactly what i was looking for! I also ended up just appending the entire line into tikz itself like tikz.append(NoEscape(fr"\draw[thick, blue] ([shift=({angle1_L}:{radius_l}cm)]{x_coord},{y_coord}) arc[start angle={angle1_L}, end angle={angle2_L}, radius={radius_l}];")) it is a very messy solution but it works too ig.

@suipiss If you find yourself using a lot of raw code like that then it may also be worth considering writing the document in LaTeX itself combined with a template language for Python such as jinja2 (which supports things like for loops and if statements) instead of trying to work around the limitations of what is supported in PyLaTeX.

@Marjin Thank you for the recs! The reason i used pylatex is because i wanted to pass in json string to make a pdf. but if jinja2 has that capability i will try to do that! thank you@

@suipiss there is also a LaTeX package for parsing json that may be interesting for your use case, see https://ctan.org/pkg/jsonparse.
